# SQLite3 Table constraint for not inserting data if last value equals

Tags: sqlite, check-constraints

I have a simple SQLite schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "test" (
  "id"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  "data"  INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

I want to *limit insertion* only if new data does not equal to last data based on order by `id DESC`.

So when having this as data:

```
1|15
2|17
```

Insertion of 15 shall succeed, but 17 should be skipped.

I can do this with 2 queries, or also with 1 query with cte or some join. But is this something possible with pure table constraints?

Comment: Do you mean order by `id DESC`?

Comment: Of course, yes - sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that SQLite can set such a constraint.
One way to do it is like this:

```
insert into tablename(data)
select ?
where ? <> coalesce((select data from tablename order by id desc limit 1), 0);
```

Replace the `?` placeholder with the new value that you want to insert.
I use `coalesce(..., 0)` so if there are no rows in the table, the new value will be compared with `0`. You can change `0` to a value that you know will never be in the column `data`.

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cAZMZWpqF5Xioobx3RExcu/1).

Answer (score 0):

I found a better approach:

What you can do to prevent repeating values to be inserted is actually creating a simple [*TRIGGER*](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) before insert.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "preventor" 
BEFORE INSERT ON "test"
WHEN (SELECT data FROM "test" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) = NEW.data
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Duplicated value detected - insertion aborted');
END
```

*NEW* is a keyword in SQLite trigger which refers the new data you're trying to insert.